# Ionic 2 - Add a component dynamically to app root

Tags: ionic2, components, root, directive

I'm trying to add a custom component dynamically (from a directive) into my Ionic 2 app root...
I've tried many things, but nothing works!
I know that I could add a container with an id to hold my custom component and reach it through an Input in my directive, but I don't want to use that solution.

I need to be able to add any custom component into app root.

This is my last attempt:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, 
         ComponentFactoryResolver,
         ViewContainerRef,
         ApplicationRef
        } from '@angular/core';
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyComponent } from '../../components/myComponent/myComponent';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()',
  }
})
export class MyDirective {
  myComponent: any;
  constructor( private  el: ElementRef,
               private  app: App,
               private  appRef: ApplicationRef,
               private  vcr: ViewContainerRef,
               private  componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
            ) {

    this.myComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);

  }

  onClick() {
    this.app._appRoot._overlayPortal._viewport.createComponent(this.myComponent);
  }
}
```

It should create my component as a sibling of _overlay elementin app root, but I only receive an error message:

```
No provider for ViewController
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion or any other solution?

Comment: I am just going put this here even if you dont want to https://github.com/apoterenko/angular2-dynamic-component

Comment: @misha130 I just had a look at the link you provide, but I don't really see how it can help with my problem. Can you explain?

Comment: Its for a container which you don't want

Comment: The solution I don't want is to add a container like this: <div id="myContainer"></div> into app.html, and then reach it through : @Input('MyContainer')... How the link you provide can help? I don't understand. Can you develop your answer?

Comment: Any answer for this? I asked a similar question recently. dynamically add custom components